# Excel splitting one row into separate rows of a fixed number of colums

Tags: excel

Here is a sample of the data I have in one row in an excel file. I would like to split it into multiple rows after every seven columns

15-Feb  20 783 175  105 $180 $973 15-Mar 31 900 58  145 $106 $140

to

15-Feb  20 783 175  105 $180 $973

15-Mar 31 900   58  145 $106 $140

Answer (score 2):

You can use this formula:

```
=INDEX($1:$1,INT(COLUMN()+(ROWS(A$5:A5)-1)*7))
```

drag/copy this formula across till row 7 and down as required.

Issue with this formula is it will return `0` ***if cell is blank***.

[image]

So alternatively, you can check for cell blank condition and write formula as:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(INDEX($1:$1,INT(COLUMN()+(ROWS(A$5:A5)-1)*7))),"",INDEX($1:$1,INT(COLUMN()+(ROWS(A$5:A5)-1)*7)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have a well defined and deterministic way to split the two halves (for instance, columns "A" to "D" is the first half, while columns "E" to "H" is the second), you can enter a formula in a different sheet like (this is pseudo-code; you will need to verify the syntax):

Cell "A1" of the new sheet: ='Other_Sheet'!A(round(row()/2)+1)

Cell "A2" of the new sheet: ='Other_Sheet'!E(round(row()/2)+1)

The indirect reference is made such that it will go to the next row in the source sheet every two rows in the new sheet.